# Is there a way to programmatically control the back-light for the android back button?

Tags: android, back-button

I'm currently making an android app and testing it on a Samsung GT-S5830.

The problem I'm having is that the back button back-light is always off when the app is running (so it's not visible), which seems to confuse the users who I have asked to test the app.

The question is whether there is a way to programmatically ensure that the back-light for the back button is always on?

I'm dubious about it, as the problem seems to be phone model dependent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is already a stackoverflow answer but I will post again:

```
private void setDimButtons(boolean dimButtons) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    LayoutParams layoutParams = window.getAttributes();
    float val = dimButtons ? 0 : -1;
    try {
        Field buttonBrightness = layoutParams.getClass().getField(
                "buttonBrightness");
        buttonBrightness.set(layoutParams, val);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    window.setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

}

Or try to find something in here (the new design is horrible ...) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

Comment: Thanks, I searched everywhere but I couldn't find it.

Comment: This doesn't work... the button lights still turn off after a few seconds of being active :/

Comment: Then add a TimerTask or Thread which calls this method e.g. 2 seconds.

Comment: PS: I found out that you have to import: android.view.Window and android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams. And something to make "Field variable" work.